# Issues installing on MacBook Pro 5.1

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, macbook, acpi

I have attempted to install the os on my 2008 mbp. 
Following the ubuntu interactions, I copied the os to usb, partitioned the ssd on the mac, did not format the new second partition and then installed reFIt and rebooted on choosing the the windows/fat option, the stayed on a screen showing only the following information
ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED
sdb no caching mode page found

and then nothing.

tried the google-fu but no ideas, any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

just did a DDG search on "ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED"
and found this page 
http://yeites.blogspot.com/2015/05/acpi-pcc-probe-failed-starting-version_29.html

From this ... it appears that there could be an SCPI issue ... I dont remember how to do this on a macbook ... but try turning it off and then see if it works

caveat -- apparently you cannot put to sleep after doing this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Gave up installing on MacBook Pro. And installed on a Lenovo. Working grand. Nice os